# How to wrap a handleClick around reactjs calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a horse race app and being new to react, I'm struggling with handling a click event when a user clicks the 'Start' button for the jockey to race. When I remove the `handleClick` function (as commented out below), the jockey races (using react's progress bar) automatically when I reload the page. I only want that functionality when I click the 'Start' button.

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Progress from 'react-progressbar';
import logo from '../../images/logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class Jockey extends Component {
  state = {
    interval: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),    
    progress: 5,
  }

  // handleClick = () => {
    // console.log('The link was clicked.');
    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval);
    }

    timer = () => {
      this.setState({ progress: this.state.progress + 1 });
      // (this.state.progress >= 99) ? this.setState({ progress: 100 }) : "" ;
      if(this.state.progress >= 99) {
         this.setState({ progress: 100 }) 
      };
    }

  // } 

  render() {
    const Buttons = () => (
      <div className="App-buttons">
        <button className="ui primary button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Start</button>
        <button className="ui button">Reset</button>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <Buttons />
        <div className="App-field">
          <h1>Race Track</h1>
          <img src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/3757315?v=4" alt=""/>
          <Progress className="App-progress" completed={this.state.progress}/>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to the React Race Hustle</h1>
        </header>
        <Jockey />
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And you should not manage state like this `this.setState({ progress: this.state.progress + 1 });`, source here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to change your code so that it satisfied your needs; hope you can see kind of changes it needed.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';


class Jockey extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      interval: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
      progress: 5,
    }
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick (){
    let that = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      that.setState((ps)=>{ 
        if(ps.progress + 1>=99) return {progress:100}
        return {progress: ps.progress + 1 }}
        );

    }, this.state.interval);
  }



render() {
  const Buttons = () => (
    <div className="App-buttons">
      <button className="ui primary button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Start</button>
      <button className="ui button">Reset</button>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Buttons />
      <div className="App-field">
        <h1>Race Track</h1>
        <img src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/3757315?v=4" alt="" />
        <div className="App-progress" completed>{ this.state.progress }</div>

    </div>
      </div >
    );
}

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Jockey />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Some comments:

- I used [functional](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) `setState` too; because what you had is not the right way to set state when state depends on value from previous state.
- You can also call `clearInterval` when component unmounts.
- And I have rendered the progress inside a div instead of a Progress component.
- and I would not put `interval` inside state; you normally don't put stuff in state if it is not used inside render.

Comment: Thanks all for the help and insight! Works now

Comment: With `ps` what are you passing as an argument?

Comment: @colin_dev256 previous state; check the link in the comments section of my answer (bottom).

Answer (score 3):

With your code as is (with the `handleClick` commented out), the `componentDidMount()` function will automatically run when the component mounts. Which means the `timer()` will begin running on the defined interval when the component mounts.

You'll want to make two changes:

1. Move the `timer()` into the handler
2. Move the `componentDidMount()` function outside the handler

```
handleClick = () => {
  console.log('The link was clicked.');
  this.interval = setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval);

  timer = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ progress: (prevState.progress + 1 > 98 ? 100 : prevState.progress + 1) });
  }
}
```

And we no longer need the `componentDidMount()` function.

Comment: I was reusing a lot of the original code and only cleaning up the parts related to the question. So I agree with you. I guess what the OP is going for is for the progress to max out at 100.